# How to copy webgl canvas? (I want minimap)

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, webgl

I want results..

[image: I want results..]

I have one webgl canvas
Is there a way to copy the webgl canvas to create a mini-map?

I invoke json and draw it on the canvas by ajax Like first picture

Original canvas and mini-map canvas  want to share coordinates and picture

The rectangle that controls the mini-map should use the draw function?

```
<div id="glCanvsDiv" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
<canvas id="glcanvas" class="canvasclass" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></canvas>
```

this is Coordinate function

```
function getWorldPosition(event) {

const pos = getNoPaddingNoBorderCanvasRelativeMousePosition(event, gl.canvas);

const x = pos.x / gl.canvas.width  *  2 - 1;
const y = pos.y / gl.canvas.height * -2 + 1;

const view = mat4.inverse(cameraMatrix);

const viewProjection = mat4.multiply(projectionMatrix, view);

const viewZ = -5;

const clip = transformPoint(projectionMatrix, [0, 0, viewZ]);

const z = clip[2];

const inverseViewProjection = mat4.inverse(viewProjection); 

var world = transformPoint(inverseViewProjection, [x, y, z]);

world[0] = -world[0];
world[1] = -world[1];

return world;
```

}

my dialog

```
<div id="aerialViewDlg" style="display:none; padding:0;">
```

```
$("#aerialViewDlg").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 300,
    height: 260,
    title: "aerialView",
    position: {
        my: "right top",
        at: "right top",
    }
});
```

I want The mini-map includes full screen,
The original canvas will only display the selected area in the mini-map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're asking. A mini map usually shows much more info than is displayed outside the mini-map. In other words the main display might show a single building where as the mini-map shows the entire town. That means the 2 things are unrelated. To draw just the building you draw a building. To draw the town you draw the town. Copying the canvas will not solve this problem for you

You can draw one canvas into another. The easiest way is if the destination canvas is a 2D canvas you just call one of the `drawImage` variations

```
ctx.drawImage(srcCanvas, dstX, dstY);
```

or

```
ctx.drawImage(srcCanvas, dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight);
```

or

```
ctx.drawImage(srcCanvas, 
              srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight,
              dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight);
```

If you want to draw the minimap in the same canvas you can enable the scissor test and set the viewport as in

```
// draw main display
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
compute projection matrix for main display
draw main display

// draw mini-map
gl.viewport(miniMapX, minMapY, miniMapWidth, minMapHeigh);
gl.scissor(miniMapX, minMapY, miniMapWidth, minMapHeigh);
gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
compute projection matrix for mini-map display
draw mini map display
```

Example:

```js
"use strict";
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");

// compiles shaders, link program, looks up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const arrays = {
  position: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
     -1, -1, 
      1, -1,
     -1,  1,
      1,  1,
    ],
  },
  indices: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      0, 1,
      1, 3,
      3, 2,
      2, 0,
    ],
  },
};
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

  // note: a good app would try to only draw what's visible in each
  // view
function drawScene(viewProjection) {  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  for (let y = -5; y <= 5; ++y) {
    for (let x = -5; x <= 5; ++x) {
      const world = m4.translation([x * 2.4, y * 2.4, 0]);
      const mat = m4.multiply(viewProjection, world);
  
      // calls gl.uniformXXX
      twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
        color: [(x + 5) / 10, (y + 5) / 10, x / 5 * y / 5 * .5 + 5, 1],
        matrix: mat,
      });
      // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
      twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo, gl.LINES);
    }
  }
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  
  // draw main scene
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

  gl.clearColor(0,0,0,1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  {
    const unitsVertical = 3;
    const half = unitsVertical * .5
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const left = -half * aspect;
    const right = half * aspect;
    const bottom = -half;
    const top = half;
    const zNear = -1;
    const zFar = 1;
    const projection = m4.ortho(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);

    const camera = m4.rotationZ(time * .1);
    const view = m4.inverse(camera);
    const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
  
    drawScene(viewProjection);
  }
  
  // draw mini map
  const miniMapWidth = gl.canvas.width / 3 | 0;
  const miniMapHeight = gl.canvas.height / 3 | 0;
  const miniMapX = gl.canvas.width - miniMapWidth;
  const miniMapY = gl.canvas.height - miniMapHeight;
  gl.viewport(miniMapX, miniMapY, miniMapWidth, miniMapHeight);
  gl.scissor(miniMapX, miniMapY, miniMapWidth, miniMapHeight);
  gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

  gl.clearColor(0.2,0.2,0.2,1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  {
    const unitsVertical = 20;
    const half = unitsVertical * .5
    const aspect = miniMapWidth / miniMapHeight;
    const left = -half * aspect;
    const right = half * aspect;
    const bottom = -half;
    const top = half;
    const zNear = -1;
    const zFar = 1;
    const projection = m4.ortho(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);

    const camera = m4.rotationZ(time * .1);
    const view = m4.inverse(camera);
    const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
  
    drawScene(viewProjection);
  }
    
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately you can't share resources across canvases in WebGL (you can't use the same buffers and textures). There are various other solutions though. See: [Display different scenes sharing resources on multiple canvases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824840/display-different-scenes-sharing-resources-on-multiple-canvases)