# Confusion with use of OffscreenCanvas.transferToImageBitmap

Tags: javascript, canvas

I just read the official MDN document of [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) and it shows an example for using [transferToImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/transferToImageBitmap).

```js
const one = document.getElementById("one").getContext("bitmaprenderer");
const two = document.getElementById("two").getContext("bitmaprenderer");

const offscreen = new OffscreenCanvas(256, 256);
const gl = offscreen.getContext("webgl");

// Perform some drawing for the first canvas using the gl context
const bitmapOne = offscreen.transferToImageBitmap();
one.transferFromImageBitmap(bitmapOne);

// Perform some more drawing for the second canvas
const bitmapTwo = offscreen.transferToImageBitmap();
two.transferFromImageBitmap(bitmapTwo);
```

The ownership of `ImageBitmap` would be consumed after execute `const bitmapOne = offscreen.transferToImageBitmap()`, so `bitmapTwo` can't consume any `ImageBitmap`. Therefore the `two` canvas can't render anything on the screen.

I'm confused with this example. Assumed I want to render the same image onto `one` and `two` canvas, I need to write the `gl` code twice, just like following:

```js
const gl = offscreen.getContext("webgl");

gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
const bitmapOne = offscreen.transferToImageBitmap();
one.transferFromImageBitmap(bitmapOne);

gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
const bitmapTwo = offscreen.transferToImageBitmap();
two.transferFromImageBitmap(bitmapTwo);
```

I don't think it is make sense to use `offscreen.transferToImageBitmap()` like the example shows. So, I want to know why the example show `bitmapOne` and `bitmapTwo` together? In what situation should I use `offscreen.transferToImageBitmap()`?

I also found that using [drawImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15840807/10090927) seems more make sense, isn't it?

```js
const one = document.getElementById('drawImage-one').getContext('2d');
const two = document.getElementById("drawImage-two").getContext("2d");
  
const offscreen = new OffscreenCanvas(300, 300);
const gl = offscreen.getContext("webgl");
  
// Perform some drawing for the two canvas using the gl context
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

one.drawImage(gl.canvas, 0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
two.drawImage(gl.canvas, 0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
```

This an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-matan-c8d8f4) to address my problem.

Comment: You read the content of the comments there? They do draw more content between each calls, so the ImageBitmap objects don't hold the same bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can either use the drawImage approach that you provided above, or use drawImage with an ImageBitmap like follows:

```js
  const one = document.getElementById("bitmap-one").getContext("2d");
  const two = document.getElementById("bitmap-two").getContext("2d");
  
  const offscreen = new OffscreenCanvas(300, 300);
  const gl = offscreen.getContext("webgl");
  
  // Perform some drawing for the first canvas using the gl context
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  const bitmap = offscreen.transferToImageBitmap();
  
  one.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
  two.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
  
  bitmap.close();
```

If you're not using workers, they are quite similar though there may be some subtle performance differences. With webworkers, using transferToImageBitmap allows you to send image data from the worker to your main page without having to pass the offscreencanvas. If you did that and wanted to draw to two canvas elements you would use the method I've provided above. This is basically the same as transferFromImageBitmap except the ImageBitmap isn't closed automatically and you will have to do so yourself. Closing it is important to have the browser release resources.

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative solution. Just like you say, the main advantage of using `transferToImageBitmap` is to facilitate the transfer of image data from a web worker to the main page. Yet, I don't see this aspect covered in the official example. Instead, it simply provides an example of using `transferToImageBitmap` twice.